# Why mysqli open transcation locks the database?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, mysqli

I am trying to use mysqli to insert the data and there is some strange behavior. For example, when I first using `$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);` and spent a several minute to run my PHP and wait for the query provided, it will hold the database until `$mysqli->commit();` , so I can not execute any other database operation . When I check the status in phpmyadmin , it show the coming SQL query status is `Waiting for table metalock` , How to fix it? Thanks

```
/* Insert log Query */
function putLog($query){
global $mysqli,$ip,$browser,$dateLog,$isQuerySuccess;
$isQuerySuccess = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO DPS_Log_$dateLog (PageID,FunctionID,ActionID,UserID,UserIP,UserInfo,LogType,Remark,LogTime) VALUES (15,20,25,25,'$ip','$browser',1,'$query',NOW())") ? true : false;
}

/* Start DB connection */
$mysqli = new mysqli(DATABASEIP, DBUSER, DBPWD, DATABASE,PORT);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$isQuerySuccess = true;

putLog ("Fail to delete: $folderPath.$item");

$isQuerySuccess ? $mysqli->commit() : $mysqli->rollback();
$mysqli->close();
```

**Update**:
    I finally found the problem is caused by another query . In short, The above coding is to insert log while the below query is to check whether the log table exist when the user login. The problem is , when I am open a transaction and try to log the operation(operation takes > 30 second) results, I can not execute the below query (wait for table metalock) so the whole system holds until the operation finished , how to fix it? thanks

```
$sql = "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$logTableName` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`PageID` int(2),
`FunctionID` int(2),
`ActionID` int(3) NOT NULL,
`UserID` int(5) NOT NULL,
`UserIP` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`UserInfo` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`LogType` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`Remark` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`LogTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
";
$this -> databaseHelper -> common_query($sql);
```

Comment: Do your operation and then get the heck out. Anyway, start at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-concepts.html - note that locking or some other form of control (e.g. MVCC) is required to maintain ACID. Exactly what is locked (and how) depends upon a number of factors.

Comment: do you want lock free way, something like add a `status` column and update it after `putlog`

Comment: Please increase your php execution time by php.ini setting

Comment: Show your *another query*.

Comment: If you need some variable that resides outside of the function's scope (`global $mysqli,$ip,$browser,$dateLog,$isQuerySuccess;`), _pass it as an argument_, don't (ab-) use `global` so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper order of things is:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ...");
$mysqli->commit();
```

But for one small insert it is weird to do it this way. In your particular case it is sufficient to do only this:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ...);
```

no autocommit disabling and no commits.

Answer (score 2):

`CREATE TABLE your_table` needs an exclusive lock on your table in order to process, but a concurrent `INSERT INTO your_table` has already placed an exclusive lock on this table. `CREATE TABLE` is put on hold until the end of the concurrent transaction, and this is the expected behaviour.

Since you are planning to not to do anything if the table exists (`IF NOT EXISTS`), you could check whether the table exists before issuing the culprit `CREATE TABLE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema
WHERE table_schema = 'your database here'
AND table_name = 'your table name here';
```

Issue this (non-blocking) query first, then issue a subsequent `CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS` only if the above returns `0`.

It is possible, although quite unlikely, that a concurrent transaction manages to create the table, and lock it, just in the middle of the execution of the above two statements. This is due to the fact that [`information_schema`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) tables are `MEMORY` tables, this engine does not support transactions (nor any form of locking). Therefore do not drop the `IF EXISTS` clause.

You could circumvent this limitation by creating your own (InnoDB) tracking table.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Please increase your php execution time by php.ini setting 

     step 1 open php.ini
     step 2 search max_execution_time 
     step 3 set max_execution_time = 3000
     step 4 save it 
     step 5 Restart  apache 
     step 6 run the program again
```

Comment: This only reduces the likelihood that the waiting time causes a time-out. It does not reduce the, waiting time or the likelihood that the query is put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Basically DDL operations are incompatible with transactions. DDL is shorthand for Data Definition Language refers to the CREATE, ALTER and DROP statements.

Try to avoid creating tables dynamically whenever possible. And have all tables created manually or with one-time scripts if needed.

If absolutely necessary try to create the table before opening the transaction.

Comment: Very good point, and it reminds me that CREATE TABLE [causes an implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html). Something to take carefully into account.

Answer (score 1):

At first one should not open transaction for only one query. Transaction comes with a cost. Pay the cost only when it's really necessary.

Secondly, it is not a good idea to create table dynamically. It shows the sigh of bad schema designing.

Assuming two query you shared must have to execute in a pair, the best way is opening a transaction. In that case open the transaction before the very first query and close it as soon as anything fails in the way which makes the whole operation unnecessary.
You can also use [Mysql Savepoint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/savepoint.html) to rollback a portion without messing the full transaction.

Here is a pseudo code for that.

```
open a transaction.

everything_is_okay=true;
try{
    do a query
    do another
    if(everything_is_not_all_right_till_now())
        throw a meaningfull exception;
    do some more query;
    savepoint A;
    and again some other query;
    if(some_partial_problem_happend())
        rollback to savepoint A;
    do hell lot of query;
}

catch(meaningfull exception){
    rollback;
}
if(every_thing_is_still_okay())
    commit;
```

By the way , even after creating a transaction , only these 2 query should not take > 30 seconds. Is there a possibility that you are looking at the wrong bucket for the spoiled eggs? :p
Do consider the fact.